# new LazyAdapter in doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-lazyadapter

I'm using a XML Parsing in doInBackground (for Load Screen) and  then set it with a LazyAdapter in the listview(list).

First the Codesample:

```
public class NewCoupons extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
             
        bar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.bar);
        new ProgressTask().execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   
          .....
          list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
          adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, xy);        
          list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
}
}
```

When I user "NewCoupons.this" I become:

> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask
>
> 1 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>
> doInBackground() 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):  at
>
> android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>
> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>
> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239) 05-15
>
> 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):     at
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>
> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>
> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319): Caused by:
>
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>
> original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>
> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746) 05-15
>
> 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):     at
>
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823) 05-15
>
> 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):     at
>
> android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1819) 05-15
>
> 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):     at
>
> android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:490) 05-15
>
> 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):     at
>
> com.example.androidhive.NewCoupons$ProgressTask.doInBackground(NewCoupons.java:170)
>
> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> com.example.androidhive.NewCoupons$ProgressTask.doInBackground(NewCoupons.java:1)
>
> 05-15 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 05-15 21:01:16.553:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(6319):   at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 05-15
>
> 21:01:16.553: E/AndroidRuntime(6319):     ... 3 more

**The Problem:** is that I cant use "this" on new LazyAdapter, that would be a error.
What I must set for "this" in new LazyAdapter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass in a context. Means, you can do this: `MyClassName.this` or `getActivity()`, if you are in a fragment.

#### Edit:

Here is your error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
> views.

Comment: Thank you. What can I do to repair the error?
When im create the list in the doInBackground I cant say: Send the Data from doInBackground to onCreate and fill the listview.

Comment: You have to do all UI stuff on the UI thread. The method on `onPostExecute()` from the Asynctask has access to the UI thread, so set the your images there.

Comment: And how I can send the _ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> **newCoupons** = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();_ ArrayList from doItBackground() to onPostExecute()

Comment: Great. He do it all but dont going in the LazyAdapter. I dont become a error bt when i test it with a System.out.println in the LazyAdapter.java - i dont become it. Do you have a idea?

Answer (score 1):

If your activity's called MainActivity use MainActivity.this